# Can't Remove `PreventDefault` Event Listener on Form Submission (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, events, preventdefault

I have a privacy policy checkbox on a form and I've set `preventDefault()` on the from submission button so the email address isn't submitted unless the checkbox is checked.

In the code below I have a simple `removeEventListener` method placed on the checkbox for when the checkbox is checked, but the code isn't working?

The `preventDefault()` method works, but the submission doesn't happen if the `privacyCheckbox.checked === true` condition is met.

```js
var mailFormSubmit = document.getElementById('mc-embedded-subscribe'),  // subscribe button
    privacyCheckbox = document.getElementById('privacy-checkbox')       // checkbox

// prevent default
function stopFormSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
}

if (privacyCheckbox.checked === false) {
    mailFormSubmit.addEventListener('click', stopFormSubmit, false)
}   

if (privacyCheckbox.checked === true) {
    mailFormSubmit.removeEventListener('click', stopFormSubmit, false)
}
```

Comment: Where does does logic live? Are you running it during an event when `privacyCheckbox` changes?

Comment: @Jacob the code above is how it is in its entirety in the my .js file for the site.

Answer (score 1):

The logic you have is just running once, so it will only take care of the initial state of the checkbox. If you want to attach/detach event listeners *whenever the checkbox changes*, you have to hook up an event listener on your checkbox:

```
const mailFormSubmit = document.getElementById('mc-embedded-subscribe'),  // subscribe button
      privacyCheckbox = document.getElementById('privacy-checkbox')       // checkbox

function stopFormSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
}

function updateSubmitBehavior() {
  if (privacyCheckbox.checked) {
    mailFormSubmit.removeEventListener('click', stopFormSubmit, false)
  } else {
    mailFormSubmit.addEventListener('click', stopFormSubmit, false)
  }
}

privacyCheckbox.addEventListener('change', updateSubmitBehavior);

updateSubmitBehavior();
```

Comment: Hi @jacob the form still submits when the checkbox isn't checked with this answer.

Comment: Does the check box start out checked or not checked? You probably have to call the function once to initialize the state. Updated accordingly.

Comment: Ah yes that works now thanks. I'll get to grips with the code tomorrow and how it works - it's very late here in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to removeEventListener simply do like this. Let me assume you are firing

**formSumitfunc** on form submit event  then your function will be

```
function formSumitfunc(e) {


    if (privacyCheckbox.checked == false) {
        e.preventDefault();

    }

    if (privacyCheckbox.checked == true) {
        // do whatever you want to do.

    } 


}
```